# How to show an Image in an email from the SharePoint document Library in SPFx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I have an email function where on click on a "SignUP" button user is notified on a outlook about his successful enrollment on that course. So I am able to send an email, but I want to display an image too in the email where the image is stored in the SharePoint document library.

So I tried with copying the image url and using img src tag to display the image but it doesn't work, so what are the other options to display the image.

```
private sendEmail(isSigningUp: boolean) {
    let emailBody = "";
    let subject = "";

    try {

        if (isSigningUp) {
            subject = "Congratulations! you have successfully signed up for task";
            emailBody = "<p><img src='https://Contos.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/SignUpImage.png' width='500' height='600'><br><br>Hi " + this.props.userDisplayName +
                ",<br><br>Congratulations! you have successfully signed up for task: " + this.state.TaskInfo.Title + ".</p>";
        }
        else {
            subject = "You have successfully withdrawn from task";
            emailBody = "<p>Hi " + this.props.userDisplayName +
                ",<br><br>You have successfully withdrawn from task: " + this.state.TaskInfo.Title + ".</p>";
        }
        CommonOperation.sendAnEmail(this.props.Context,[this.props.Context.pageContext.user.email], subject, emailBody);
    }
    catch (e) {
        CommonLogger.LogError(this.props.Context, Constants.ApplicationName, "TaskTile.tsx-sendEmail()", e.message, "", "", "3");
    }
}
```

Also here's the sendAnEmail function through which an email is getting sent

```
public static sendAnEmail(context: any, to: any, subject: string, emailBody:any) {
    sp.utility.sendEmail({
        To: to,
        Subject: subject,
        Body: emailBody,
        AdditionalHeaders: {
            "content-type": "text/html"
        }
    }).then(() => {
        alert('Email Sent! ');
    }).catch((error) => {
        CommonLogger.LogError(context, Constants.ApplicationName, FILE_NAME+"sendAnEmail()", "Email not sent" + error.message, "", "", "2");
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your `<img>` tag is not actually part of the string you are assigning to the `emailBody` variable, so of course it's not showing up in the email.

Comment: Hi @DylanCristy, I've made changes in the question now I've inserted that inside the email body but still it is displaying the blank image. Any Suggestions could you provide?

Comment: PS, I did inspect element in outlook so it shows blockedimgsrc, so maybe that could be the reason it is not getting displayed how to overcome this?

Comment: Anyways got the solution, few changes was needed in the outlook settings so did that and it worked.

Comment: Base64 encode the image and embed it into the message, then it wont get blocked as an external image by Outlook.